# Working with data - C programming

Tags: c, file-handling

Ive written this code, to read data from a sensor:

```
char c;
do{
    while(!read(fd, &c, 1));    
} while (c!='$');   

do{
    while(!read(fd, &c, 1));    
} while (c!=',');   

do{
    while(!read(fd, &c, 1));

    printf("%c",c); 
    fp = fopen("/var/www/Sensor_data.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%c%", c);
    fclose(fp); 

} while (c!='\n');
```

The file then looks like

> 518.088131,**0.272969,0.376242,0.522998,0.368944,0.347478,0.343025,0.252323**,0.612587,0.552753,0.120302,806.230415

I would then like a way to procces this data, so I take data number 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (the ones in bold) and transfer to new files one for each.
Anyone can give an example of a program doing this? or preferred to modify my program so it makes a file with all data, and 7 other files with 1 data in each.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the way you read data. If you get an error reading from the sensor, you will probably be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: putting the open and close inside the do loop is SLOW.  open only once, before the do loop then close only once after the loop exits.

Comment: it would be a very good idea to perform the reading by first using select() to wait for the data to be available, read all the data into a buffer, then discard the leading $...., then write the remaining, in a single write, to the output file.  This will be MUCH faster and much less burden on the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick. Not very scalable though :S

```
// This part has to go before main function starts
char int_to_char(int n){
    return (char) n + (int)'0';
}

// and this replaces what you already had
int reading = 1;
do{
    while(!read(fd, &c, 1));          // <- you should change this

    printf("%c",c); 
    fp = fopen("/var/www/Sensor_data.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
    fclose(fp); 

    if (c == ',')
        reading++ ;

    else{        
        if (reading >= 2 && reading <= 8){              // 2nd to 8th reading
            char temp[] = "/var/www/Sensor_data .txt";  // <- Added a space, which I'm 
                                                    //  gonna substitute with a number
            temp[20] = int_to_char(reading);            // Substitute the space
            fp = fopen(temp, "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

} while (c!='\n');
```

The conversion from int to char only works if the number is between 0 and 9.

Comment: hmm i get your idea, but when i try to run the program i get "Segmentation Fault" :/ any idea why?

Comment: @Jacob I think I solved the problem. I was allocating temp in read-only memory, which was causing problems. Please try this version and tell me if it worked :D

Comment: hmm it can compile and run. but the files created is just called Sensor_data?.txt and when i write sudo nano Sensor_data?.txt it opens 7 files filled with random number. So im not sure the write to different files part works. Seems like it doesent get the right data at least

Comment: it writes 2 4 . 1 1 8 3 each value is in a file for it self. The value of the first measurement is 524.126453 so it seems like it skips the 5 and take the 7 next values, instead of jumping to the intended values 2-8

Comment: @Jacob I noticed the bug when I was reviwing the code bug forgot to edit it here. The problem is that the conversion from (int) reading -> char is not smooth. I'm updating my post.

Comment: Now the files are created the intended way. But the data written to the files is still wrong? it still does the same as i described, where it skips the 5 and writes the 7 next digits of the first measurement. Where the plan is to skip the first measurements and then take 7 next and skip the rest

Comment: This is like the whack a mole xD I'm incrementing reading every time a new character is read. We should only do that when it's ','. Updating...

Comment: :D well thanks for the help no matter what! cant understand either why it doesent just read after each comma.

Comment: @Jacob I tested it a bit and its working as intended now on my end. Please tell me if you have any troubles!

Comment: i wrote a new post to better explain my troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
FILE *fp;   
    char c;
    do{
        while(!read(fd, &c, 1));    
    }while (c!='$');    

    char int_to_char(int n){
    return (char) n + (int)'0';
}

int reading = 1;
do{
    while(!read(fd, &c, 1));          // <- you should change this

    printf("%c",c); 
    fp = fopen("/var/www/Sensor_data.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
    fclose(fp); 

    if (c == ',')
        reading++ ;

    else{        
        if (reading >= 2 && reading <= 8){              // 2nd to 8th reading
            char temp[] = "/var/www/Sensor_data .txt";  // <- Added a space, which I'm 
                                                    //  gonna substitute with a number
            temp[20] = int_to_char(reading);            // Substitute the space
            fp = fopen(temp, "a");
            fprintf(fp, "%c", c);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

} while (c!='\n');
```

I get 523.488072,**0.326624,0.471786,0.472091,0.317701,0.430966,0.292683,0.260292**,0.653686,0.608487,0.116710,806.211857 in the Sensor_data.txt file.
In the other 7 files i get 2 3 . 4 8 8 0. 1 value in each file.
What i intend is to get the 7 value marked with bold into 7 separate files. I dont know if this was clear and if its whats happening for you SlySherZ?

Just read that the conversion between int to char only works if the number it between 0-9 could this be the problem?

Comment: @Jacob this code won't run because you defined a function in the wrong place.

Comment: Got it to work now :) thanks a lot for the help and patience! SlySherZ